# Is dumping a lot of DataInputStreams bad practice?

Tags: java, datainputstream

Let's say I have a data class that holds a 3-dimensional vector.

```
class Vec3 {
    float x, y, z;
    public Vec3(float x, float y, float z) { /* ... */ } 
}
```

Then I want to give it the functionality to be read from a stream. I have floats, so the easiest choice is a `DataInputStream`.

```
public static Vec3 read(DataInputStream in) {
    float x = in.readFloat();
    float y = in.readFloat();
    float z = in.readFloat();
    return new Vec3(x, y, z);
}
```

And, of course, I want it to support all `InputStream` types. So, I'll create an overload that wraps any stream.

```
public static Vec3 read(InputStream in) {
    return read(new DataInputStream(in));
}
```

However, this method creates a `DataInputStream` that is never closed and just dumped after reading. Is this bad practice and can it cause problems? What if I have a lot of `Vec3`'s to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DataInputStream` is a thin wrapper over `InputStream`, with almost no resources of its own. Their `close()` method only closes the wrapped input stream. Creating lots of them only means creating many temporary objects for the GC to collect. There is no danger in creating and discarding many `DataInputStream` objects, but if you are trying to optimize for performance you may want to avoid it.

On the other hand, trying to support all input stream types seems like an over-generalization to me. I would make the method accept just `DataInputStream`, or the `DataInput` interface.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, what you are proposing to do is safe.  (A `DataInputStream` doesn't do any buffering ... though there is a potential issue with read-ahead if you use the deprecated `readLine` method.)

However, creating lots of temporary `DataInputStream` instances does have associated costs, so if you care about performance you should avoid doing that.

---

> And, of course, I want it to support all InputStream types ....

I don't see the "of course".  If it is going to have performance implications, then maybe you *shouldn't* do that.  Simply doing it because you *think* someone *might* want to use the overload is probably a bad idea.

On the other hand, you could just leave it to the programmer who is using your API to decide whether or not to use the "convenience" overloads.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the signature to DataInputStream and force the caller to provide it. Then conserving them is the caller's problem :-) but he is also in a much better position to be able to conserve them than you are.